# DC, BLDC or stepper motor as a generator

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, stepper-motor

Which type of motor is better to use as a generator? I know that I can directly use the DC energy generated when using a DC motor. Will I need a full bridge diode rectifier circuit to use the energy that the stepper motor will produce?

Is a 3-phase rectifier circuit sufficient to convert the energy produced by BLDC to DC and use it?

Comment: A stepper motor won't really work as a generator. I am assuming you mean a Brushed DC motor when you say DC motor? A BLDC motor is more effiecent and more complicated than the brushed version, but you need to have a BLDC controller, which isn't quite a 3-phase rectifier (though is pretty close assuming a 3-phase BLDC motor)

Comment: @Puffafish Why won't a stepper motor work as a generator? I've played with turning a hybrid stepper motor by hand to generate tiny amounts of electricity. My motor can at least produce enough power to turn another identical stepper motor or to produce a loud sound through a pair of headphones. I used a multimeter and found that I could get the output voltage up to about 1 V with no load. It's not clear to me why you couldn't get more electric power out by putting more mechanical power in.

Comment: @TannerSwett A stepper motor moves in steps. Each of these steps is a digital position. So when rotating a stepper motor you have a pulse for each step, then a dead point, then a pulse. You get some voltage, you get some power. But the motor is not designed to be spun, it's designed to go from step to step.

Answer (score 1):

A stepper motor won't really work as a generator. I suggest you read up as to how stepper motors function for you to understand this.

I am assuming you mean a Brushed DC motor when you say DC motor? A BLDC can operate around 80-90% efficient, but a brushed one is usually no higher than 75%. So a BLDC is clearly better from a performance point of view, but the control is a lot more complicated.

You mention a 3-phase rectifier, which makes me think you need to do a lot more research into how motors work. A BLDC motor needs to have a controller in order to work as wel las it can. This is true if your running it as a motor or as a generator.

You need to have a controller for the BLDC to do the commutation, which is the job of the brushes in a brushed DC motor. You can buy many BLDC controllers off the shelf, but some don’t work as generators. You need to be very careful to choose the controller to match your motor. This includes whatever position sensing you’re going for: hall effect, sensor-less or something else. Power, speed and torque, as well as voltage and current all need to be considered.

A 3-phase rectifier may or may not do some (possibly all) of what you need depending on the type of load you have. But it won’t be as efficient or as useful as using a proper matched controller.

The problem is you have an input which is a variable speed and a variable load, and you want to draw a not defined power from it. An intelligent BLDC controller would be able to draw peak power out of the system all the time, which you could store in a battery for whatever electrical purpose you have. Meanwhile a DC brushed motor will spin at whatever speed, voltage and current out varying with input and load.

To directly answer your question: BLDC with a good controller is the best bet. A brushed DC motor will be simpler but with significant performance limitations.

Comment: I found a BLDC at the company I work for and disassembled the control circuit. I built 3 phase rectifier circuits and connected LED as output. I was able to turn on the LED when I turned the BLDC by blowing. I measured an output voltage of 5V when I blew it fast enough.

Comment: He wants to use the motor as a generator. You don't need a controller, only a 3 phase rectifier to use a BLDC as a generator. The rectifier may need to be followed by a buck or boost to handle speed variations.

Comment: What about inner rotor design and outer rotor design? Does it matter which one I use?

Comment: @Neil_UK there is no defined load. You'll get something at a fixed input speed and torque, but it needs everything being steady state. If you want something that'll produce some power, then yes you can get away with a 3-phase rectifier (if the BLDC is 3 phase), as mentioned in my 5 para.

Answer (score 0):

A typical simple DC stepper motor has two coils 90 offset to each other and thus will generate two sine waves offset by 90 degrees. You can rectify either or both with full wave rectifiers or connect them in series (end of one coil’s winding to beginning of another’s winding); or in parallel after having rectified both with diodes to prevent reverse current when one goes high and other is low (remember 90 degree offset). In fact a DC stepper isn’t that much different from a BLDC / PMSM, the latter typically having 3 coils 120 degrees offset to each other (3 x 120 = 360) and connected in Y or Delta while the former has just two independent windings with 90 degrees offset. Therefore practically all that’s been said here about BLDC / PMSM acting as a generator is also applicable to steppers with minor adjustments according to the differences in their internal construction described above.